# Getting full HTTP request from website

Tags: macos, terminal, http

I am doing a project in which my Arduino needs to connect to a simple web page and retrieve the content of a text file. I want to use `curl` to see the response I would get if I sent the following HTTP request once connected to `example.com` (the website in my actual project is a different one) so that I can devise a parse for the contents of `commandPage.txt`:

```
GET /commandPage.txt HTTP 1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
```

How can I use `curl` to send the request and see the full response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is simply:

```
curl http://example.com/commandPage.txt
```

This will get you the contents of that URL.

If you need to see the headers as well, you can add `-v`.

Otherwise, you can even use `telnet` to do so. Just use:

```
telnet example.com 80
```

And paste the full request as quoted above, followed by one empty line.

Comment: Thank you! The telnet did not work for me, but the curl worked! Yes, I didn't mean to put the mail.horacemann.org. Oops.

Comment: I have edited your question (pending approval) and my answer.